# Updation to subject is not happening in Rxjs

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6

I'm trying to update an RxJS Subject via a component's method . But it is not happening properly .

```
cricketData$ = new Subject<string>();

ngOnChanges() {
  this.cricketData$
    .asObservable()
    .pipe(
      tap(() =>
        console.log(
          'Triggering REST call for cricket tab with the year ',
          this.year
        )
      ),
      take(1)
    )
    .subscribe();
  this.cricketData$.next('sachin');
}

updateCricketData() {
   this.cricketData$.next('dravid');
}
```

If I remove the **take** operator , subject is updated . But multiple service calls are triggered while selecting the values from dropdown . Is there any other operator / approach in RxJS using which I can achieve the below scenarios?

1. service calls are triggered only once while selecting the values from dropdown
2. subject is also updated via component's method

Please refer the below StackBlitz link . Thanks in advance .

Editor URL Stackblitz: [EditorURL](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tfrvqw?file=src/app/sports/sports.component.html)

App URL Stackblitz: [AppURL](https://angular-ivy-tfrvqw.stackblitz.io)

Comment: First of all why you put subscribe() method inside ngOnChanges() method ?

Comment: because without subcribe() , I cannot trigger the REST call which is happening inside of pipe

Comment: If you can take a look at the stackblitz , sports is the parent component and cricket is the child component . On changing the values in dropdown in sports component , REST call should be triggered in cricket component . 

On changing the dropdown value , multiple calls were triggered . So I applied take(1) to restrict it to single service call . 

Now the problem is service call is not triggered if I update the subject via a component's method .

Comment: `this.cricketData$.next('sachin');` then what this line of code do for you ?

Comment: It's an initial value for the subject . so that we can see a rest call being triggered

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240091/discussion-between-grd-and-anusha-krishnamurthy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues.
**First**:
`ngOnChanges` triggers multiple times, and every time you change the value you are adding a new pipe working parallelly.
`take(1)` makes your previous pipe stop and only the recent pipe `tab` is triggered.

```
ngOnInit(): void { // runs once
    this.cricketData$
      .asObservable()
      .pipe( // runs on every next
        tap(() =>
          console.log(
            'Triggering REST call for cricket tab with the year ',
            this.year
          )
        )
      )
      .subscribe();
  }

  ngOnChanges() {
    this.cricketData$.next('sachin'); // runs on every event on the page
  }
```

**Second** issue: Do you really want to trigger this function on ngChange whenever there's an update on the page rather than just the dropdown, if the answer is only when there is a change in the dropdown then you can use a combination of `Input set year(value: string)`

[example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gj74fp?file=src/app/sports/cricket/cricket.component.ts)

```
    export class CricketComponent implements OnChanges {
  private _selectedYear: string;

  @Input() set year(value: string) {
    this._selectedYear = value;
    this.cricketData$.next('sachin'); // will trigger with every drop down change
  }

  cricketData$ = new Subject<string>();

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.cricketData$
      .asObservable()
      .pipe(
        tap((value) =>
          console.log(
            'Triggering REST call for cricket tab with the year ',
            this._selectedYear,
            value
          )
        )
      )
      .subscribe();
  }

  ngOnChanges() {}

  updateCricketData() {
    this.cricketData$.next('dravid');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using a formcontrol for the year selector, we can listen to the changes of the formcontrol and the subject you have created with `combineLatest`, which will trigger when either of them emit (as long as they have emitted at least once). Don't know your exact case of how/when your subject is updated initially, so I just added a `startWith(null)` value. Apply it to your usecase...

So the formcontrol for the parent:

```ts
year = new FormControl(2019);
```

and template where we mark the form control as well as pass the formcontrol to the child:

```html
<select [formControl]="year">
  <option value="2019">2019</option>
  <option value="2020">2020</option>
  <option value="2021">2021</option>
</select>

<app-cricket [year]="year"></app-cricket>
```

Then the child listens to this in `OnInit` together with the Subject:

```ts
ngOnInit() {
  combineLatest([
    this.year.valueChanges.pipe(startWith(this.year.value)),
    this.cricketData$.asObservable().pipe(startWith(null)),
  ]).pipe(
    switchMap(values => {
      return REST API request...
    })
  ).subscribe(result => console.log(result))
}
```

Using `startWith` to make them trigger initially. Remember to unsubscribe!!

**[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xjjecn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fsports%2Fcricket%2Fcricket.component.ts)** (without the `switchMap`)